# Formulas for mass of nucleus and atom. Looking for clarification

Tags: nuclear-physics

I've been searching the internet for a formula for nuclear mass which accounts for various interactions present. I've encountered the following formulas:

$$m = Zm_p + (A-Z)m_n  - \frac{B}{c^2}$$

$$m = Z(m_p+m_e) + (A-Z)m_n - \frac{B}{c^2} -\frac{b}{c^2}$$

$$m = Z(m_p+m_e) + (A-Z)m_n - \frac{B}{c^2}$$

I have a feeling that the $m$'s and $B$'s aren't the same thing in different formulas.

In the first one it looks like we're ignoring the electrons, and $B$ appears to be the binding energy between two nucleons. So $m$ is the mass of the nucleus?

The second one includes the electrons, as well as $b$ which seems to be the binding energy between the nucleons and electrons? I'm not entirely sure on what $b$ is. The capital $B$ looks like it's the same thing, but $m$ means the mass of the entire atom?

The third one is a mystery, it includes the mass of the electrons, but not the little $b$. Perhaps it's an approximation to the second formula?

I'm looking for clarification regarding these formulas. What are the conditions regarding their usability? What do the $m$'s and $B$'s stand for?

Comment: It may depend on the context which is missing here. You can't mindlessly copy-paste around formulas.

Comment: That's the point, I don't know the context and am trying to find out.

Comment: Well, where did you find them?

Comment: For a more complete answer, look up the "semi-empirical mass formula".

Comment: That's where I got the first formula from. So that's the mass of the nucleus. Is the second one then for the mass of the entire atom, or a better version of the mass of the nucleus? I got that one from some online lecture notes, but there is barely any explanation.

Comment: @DepeHb still, it will be very very helpful if you _edit the question_ to link to where you found each of these formulas.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question?